# Fetch - sending POST data

Tags: fetch-api

My PHP script isn't receiving anything via POST from **fetch**. What am I doing wrong?

Javascript:

```
fetch("http://127.0.0.1/script.php", {
    method: "post",
    body: "inputs=" + JSON.stringify({param: 7})
  }).then(response => response.json()).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

script.php:

```
  echo "\nprinting POST:\n";
  print_r($_POST);

  echo "\nprinting GET:\n";
  print_r($_GET);
  die();
```

Console:

> printing POST: Array ( )
>
> printing GET: Array ( )

Comment: Take a look in your browser's developer tools. You'll be able to see the requests and responses, which should help figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was something wrong with the htaccess file for that particular test PHP file. I've used it for posting something to the main project folder/PHP files and it went ok.

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding any url parameters (hence `$_GET` is empty) and you're not setting a `Content-Type` header that will make PHP automatically parse the request body. (hence `$_POST` is empty).